# affdex-sdk: FaceTracking SDK for Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, tracking, face, affdex-sdk

Can someone please refer any resource/project which uses http://www.affectiva.com/ to track face and extract landmark points in Unity3D

Tutorial here only refers to the emotion extraction
http://developer.affectiva.com/v2_2/unity/

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this (from http://developer.affectiva.com/v2_2/unity/analyze-camera/).

```
using Affdex;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PlayerEmotions : ImageResultsListener
{
    public FeaturePoint[] featurePointsList;

    public override void onFaceFound(float timestamp, int faceId)
    {
        Debug.Log("Found the face");
    }

    public override void onFaceLost(float timestamp, int faceId)
    {
        Debug.Log("Lost the face");
    }

    public override void onImageResults(Dictionary<int, Face> faces)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Face> pair in faces)
        {
            int FaceId = pair.Key;  // The Face Unique Id.
            Face face = pair.Value;    // Instance of the face class containing emotions, and facial expression values.

            //Retrieve the coordinates of the facial landmarks (face feature points)
            featurePointsList = face.FeaturePoints;

            // do something with the feature points
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anshul Jhawar if this answered your question, please accept it.  Thanks.